# Android calculate and color each pixel of screen

Tags: android, ondraw

I have to match the below requirements.

1. There is a circle (source) which is on the bottom right of the screen.
2. I have to calculate the distance between the source from every pixel on screen.
3. If the distance is above some range, the color of each pixel should change.

I've been doing android for some years but never had a chance to do such thing. I really don't expect a full answer, but where should I start from? Please help.

Comment: If you change each pixel color then it not just showing because its very small to see.

Comment: Well, it should be done for every pixel. I expect to see some visual outputs on the screen.